# Return MySQL query in PHP using mysqli class

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

It appears that I am connecting to a MySQL database but unable able to return a query using mysqli class. I've done some searches and what I have coded should return the results, but I am missing something.

```
   <?php

set_include_path('/Applications/MAMP/db/mysql57');

$host = "127.0.0.1";
$user = "admin";
$password = " ";
$bookDatbase = "Books";

$mysqli = new mysqli($host,$user, $password, $bookDatabase);

if ($mysqli->connect_errno) {
    printf("Connect failed: %s\n", $mysqli->connect_error);
    exit();
}

$result = $mysqli->query("SELECT Title FROM Book");

echo $result;
```

Comment: What else does it return if not the results?

Comment: Hi, you have typo in $bookDatbase/$bookDatabase

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$conn = new mysqli("localhost","username","password","Books");

$result = $conn->query("SELECT Title FROM Book");

if(mysqli_error($conn)){
    echo mysqli_error($conn);
}
else{

    $titles = [];

    while ($r = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){
        $titles[] = $r;
    }

    echo "<pre>";
    print_r($titles);
    echo "</pre>";
}
```

Comment: Yes!!! That worked Thank you! I see that I needed to pass the values to an array. Also, because of how you designed the code I was able to see yet another typo in the query. It should have been "Books" and not "Book"

Comment: I am glad it helped you :)

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass mysqli object as well as below:

```
$result = mysqli_query($mysqli, "SELECT Title FROM Book");
```

Hope it helps you.

Comment: The second $mysqli is reduntant.